# Entity Framework OnModelCreating One to Many

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create a one to many relationship between the AspNetUsers table and another table called rules. A user can have multiple rules.

Since AspNetUsers already exists, I do not wish to recreate the table. Inside my data context class, I added this code:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Ignore<AspNetUser>();
    }
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to link the tables. How do I instruct Entity Framework ignore migrations on the AspNetUser class and add a table relationship?

Here is my class:

```
    public class RuleSet
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string SetName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ObjectEnum ObjectType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public AspNetUser AspNetUserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ActionEnum Action { get; set; }

    public string ActionValue { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Rule> Rules { get; set; } = new List<Rule>();
}
```

Comment: [Exclude tables from migrations](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-efcore-5-0-rc1/#exclude-tables-from-migrations)

Comment: `public AspNetUser AspNetUserId ...`, the property's type is rather interger/guid?

Comment: In general there is nothing you need to do with `AspNetUser` table, because it should be unaffected (it is the principal of the one-to-many relationship, hence the FK will be in the other entity/table).

Comment: Use AspNetUserId should say string.